# complex type 'mixedDataType': The content model is not determinist. magento 2.4.5

Tags: products, elasticsearch, magento2.4.5

I have an issue on a Magento 2.4.5.

I got below error.

1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationSchemaException): Processed schema file: /home/public_html/vendor/magento/module-elasticsearch/etc/esconfig.xsd
complex type 'mixedDataType': The content model is not determinist.
Line: 18

after changing search engine Elasticsearch to MySQL then index command working.

Comment: verify elastic search version, maching with magento requirement or not.

Comment: version" : {
    "number" : "7.15.0",
    "build_date" : "2021-09-16",
    "lucene_version" : "8.9.0",

Comment: Please search for this string in your module paths, such as in the app and vendor directories. There might be an issue defined in your XML file.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/371144/complex-type-mixeddatatype-the-content-model-is-not-determinist try this link and Temporary fix  @kiran

Answer (score 2):

First backup this file then remove one line check it

> vendor/magento/module-elasticsearch/etc/esconfig.xsd

```
<xs:element type="xs:string" name="default" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
```

this line removes only

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
/**
* This schema must be used to validate esconfig.xml files
*
* Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
* See COPYING.txt for license details.
*/
-->
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element name="config" type="configType" />
<xs:complexType name="configType" mixed="true">
  <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1">
     <xs:element name="stemmer" type="mixedDataType" />
     <xs:element name="stopwords_file" type="mixedDataType" />
  </xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="mixedDataType">
   <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1">
      <xs:any processContents="lax" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
   </xs:choice>
  </xs:complexType>
 </xs:schema>
```

After run command then check it.

Answer (score 1):

This error has happened since ea-libxml2 was updated from ea-libxml2-2.11.5-1.1.2.cpanel.x86_64 to ea-libxml2-2.12.2-1.2.1.cpanel.x86_64

Temporary fix to get the site working again was to downgrade:

```
yum downgrade ea-libxml2-2.11.5-1.1.2
```

Now have to work out why the xml files don't work with the new package

Answer (score 0):

You can reference This answer: My issue was resolved with this solution, But I am not sure Whether this solution might have some backward compatibility issues.
Please apply first on the dev or local environment before on the production environment

> ***[complex type 'mixedDataType': The content model is not determinist](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/371144/complex-type-mixeddatatype-the-content-model-is-not-determinist)***